# Give columns numeric names

Tags: r

I've imported an Excel file that uses numbers for column headers.  To play with it, I'm trying to reproduce a very small version of the data set in the following way:

```
Country <- c("A", "C")
`1990` <- c(100,200)
`2000` <- c(200,300)
`2020` <- c(100,300)
pop <- data.frame(Country, `1990`, `2000`, `2020`)
setnames(pop, old=c(`1990`,`2000`, `2020`), new=c("1990","2000","2020"))
```

Besides trying to use `setnames()` I've tried using `names()` and assigning numbers rather than strings, but in every case it prepends an "X".  In order for my toy example to match the real thing I'm eventually going to try to operate on, I need this not to be the case.  How can I accomplish that?

Comment: see `check.names` in `data.frame()`

Comment: This is an [untidy data format](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) with values in the column names. Reshape to long form, and lots of problems will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

pop <- data_frame(
  Country = c("A", "C"),
  `1990` = c(100, 200),
  `2000` = c(200, 300),
  `2020` = c(100, 300)
)
```